# Roxygen getting cannot open file/permission denied/execution halted

Tags: r, devtools, r-package, roxygen

So I've been trying to build and load a package and have been getting this error

```
devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))

Updating stat290.ass2 documentation
Loading stat290.ass2
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages ... topic_add_examples -> read_lines -> <Anonymous> -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\blah\Desktop\stat290.ass2': Permission denied
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

I've seen these posts as reference: [Roxygen Warning "cannot open the connection" "Permission Denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51641469/roxygen-warning-cannot-open-the-connection-permission-denied), https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/766, but they say the error has been patched out. I have tried deleting and re-installing both devtools and roxygen2, but have not had any luck

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by removing the `@return` and `@example` in my roxygen2 comments at the header of the function as I did not write anything in for them.  It appears that if you put a `@XXX` you need to fill in the information next to it, otherwise the key is missing the value and it bombs.

I got he idea from the error `topic_add_examples -> read_lines ->` since it appeared it was trying to read the comments next to my `@example` but I didn't have any.

Comment: This is an `roxygen2` bug which should now be fixed: https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/issues/1152#issuecomment-1090184884